# iTunes COM Interface Jscript question

Tags: javascript, itunes

How do you correctly use ItemByName()?

```
HRESULT IITTrackCollection::ItemByName  (  [in] BSTR  name,  
  [out, retval] IITTrack **  iTrack 
 )
```

This is what the documentation provides but I can't figure out how to get it to work...

```
foundTrack = tracks.ItemByName("Track Name");
        WScript.Echo(foundTrack.Artist);
```

What if I have more than one song with this track name?  How do I note that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITTTrackCollection has a search function which lets you search by several fields.  It's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in case of multiple tracks with the same name, `ItemByName` returns the track with the lowest `trackID` value.